# Inserting two file with different preambles

Tags: include

Is it possible to insert a LaTeX file into another file without the same preamble?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Sure this is possible, but I think you should provide an example of the files you want to include. It is not clear to me exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: See the [TeX FAQ multi-doc question](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multidoc) for some approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I get your question right, but I guess you want to include one full LateX-document into another. For this you could try the `includex`-package. This package is not included in the standard TeX Live-distribution as it is in an unstable-branch of [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/includex). In MikTeX it's included in package `frankenstein`. With this package you can do something like this:

```
% this is file input.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Dies ist der Text von input.
\end{document}
```

Now you use this file included in the main document (this is not working with `\include`- or `\input`-command!). It's important to load all packages used in the included files in the main file, as the preamble of the included files is ignored while processing main!

```
% this is file main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{includex}
\begin{document}
Dieser Text ist in main.
\includedocskip{input.tex}
\end{document}
```